# Erro ao tentar executar uma classe

Tags: java, netbeans

Este é o meu primeiro post aqui no stack, estou tendo dificuldades executando essa classe no NetBeans. Estou usando a versao 1.8.0_40 do Java, já tentei pesquisar sobre alguma solução, mas não achei.

```
public class Dialog1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bem Vindo ao Java");
    }

}
```

ao compilar essa classe ele até da como sucesso, mas da uma mensagem de erro

> run: Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal
>   dialog1.Dialog1 Java Result: 1 CONSTRUÍDO COM SUCESSO (tempo total: 1
>   segundo)

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Este erro parece que está relacionado a configuração do projeto, se você criou um projeto Java, veja nas propriedades se está setado corretamente a jre correta para execução.

Comment: Sugiro tentar executar o programa por linha de comando. Se pela linha de comando não tiver problemas, é algo na IDE mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser que esteja faltando o import no começo do arquivo:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

Answer (score 0):

Falta a importação da classe `JOptionPane`. Assim como já dito pelo Victor, você pode importá-la com `import javax.swing.JOptionPane;` no início do código.
Mas como nesse caso você só está usando ela uma vez, poderia fazer assim:

```
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bem vindo ao java!");
```

Nesse caso, está "chamando" a classe para ser usada apenas nessa linha. Se precisar dela de novo, terá que repetir esse comando.